# SSAS - Cube Deployment Error SQL Server 2014 Enterprise - VS 2015

Tags: sql-server, ssas, sql-server-data-tools

I've created a adventure works cube for my learning purpose on `Azure` VM.

- Multidimensional 
  When I try to deploy Visual studio throws up this error.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the error please?

Comment: Is this a Tabular model or Multidimensional? I'm assuming Tabular but would like confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy a cube on SQL Server 2014, you must create it in Visual Studio 2013.

Visual Studio 2015 creates cubes for SQL Server 2016, which is why the cube has a compatibility level that SQL Server 2014 doesn't know how to handle.

Comment: Thanks for the response but is there no alternative ?

Comment: Problem still persist.
Since I'm on VM, I took the opportunity to add SQL Server 2016 and tried to deploy on SQL Server 2016 and still the same error.

Comment: If the error still mentions "compatibility level" then I would move this question to dba.stackexchange.com.   They will be better equipped to help solve it.

Comment: Thanks @Taballeman  Not sure how to move question to dba.Stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can build the project locally and edit the database file and change the compatability line to 1100 and deploy to the SSAS server manually via the deployment wizard.